# Выборка строк из бд с limit mysql

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть данная таблица

```
SELECT id FROM users order by id DESC
id
10|
9 |
8 |
7 |
6 |
5 |
4 |
3 |
2 |
1 |
```

```
SELECT id FROM users order by id ASC
id
1 |
2 |
3 |
4 |
5 |
6 |
7 |
8 |
9 |
10|
```

Как я могу сделать данную выборку? С `LIMIT 5`.

```
id
6 |
7 |
8 |
9 |
10|
```

Comment: `SELECT id FROM users order by id ASC LIMIT 5, 5`

Comment: @Denis640Kb выводит в обратном порядке вверху 5 внизу 1

Comment: Верно, прошу прощения. Используйте `ASC` вместо `DESC`

Comment: @Denis640Kb получилось, а можете подробнее рассказать про `LIMIT 5, 5`, если записей неизвестное количество, а нужно вывести 20 в нужном порядке как описал выше.

Comment: Используйте оконные функции - ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин в данном случае `LIMIT` будет брать 5 записей не учитывая первые 5. Т.е. начиная с 6 вернёт следующие 5 записей. Это тоже самое, что и использование `OFFSET`. К примеру, в данном случае это равносильно  `SELECT id FROM users order by id ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5` Если Вам необходимо вывести последние 10 записей в таблице, то Вы используете вместо `ASC` `DESC`. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример смоделированной ситуации, когда не знаете сколько записей. С какой стороны хотите выбрать и сколько.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Нужно выбрать последние 20 строк в порядке как я описал вышел, допустим 100 строк а вывести нужно 80, 81, 82 ... 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отсортировать и получить данные в таком порядке, как Вы указали можно при помощи:

```
SELECT id FROM users order by id ASC LIMIT 5, 5
```

Где отчёт начинается сначала. И начиная с 6 записи будут браться 5 последующие.

Если Вы хотите получить последние 5 записей, и отсортировать их по возрастанию, то можете воспользоваться следующим:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM users order by id DESC LIMIT 5) AS Z ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, второй вариант подходит.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Да не за что. Рад помочь. )